# grunt-contrib-copy syntax for process option confusion

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm trying to replace some placeholders in different files as I copy. My gruntfile works fine, but adding in the process option to do the replacements, it's just not working. Below is the relevant section of my gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    copy: {
        js: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'src/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/',
                src: ['**/*.js'],
                dest: 'public/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/'
            }],
            options: {
                process: function ( content ) {
                    console.log( content );
                    content = content.replace( /pilauBreakpointLarge/g, breakpoints.large );
                    content = content.replace( /pilauBreakpointMedium/g, breakpoints.medium );
                    return content;
                }
            }
        },
    }

});
```

The paths can be understood in the context of the code on GitHub: https://github.com/pilau/starter (the public directory isn't committed to the repo because it's a starter theme). Those paths are variables in my original Gruntfile, and are working fine in all other tasks.

All the vars are set up OK. I've included the `console.log( content )` to check if the process function's actually running - it doesn't seem to be, so I guess it's basic syntax.

There's an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28600474/1087660) which seems to address this, but as far as I can tell, that way of doing it is simply bad JS syntax - not sure how it got marked as right.

`--verbose` output for running the copy task:

```
Running "copy:js" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.js exists in config...OK
Files: src/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/admin.js -> public/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/admin.js
Files: src/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/flickity.js -> public/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/flickity.js
Files: src/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/global.js -> public/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/global.js
Files: src/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/modernizr.js -> public/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/modernizr.js
Files: src/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/picturefill.js -> public/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/picturefill.js
Files: src/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/respond.js -> public/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/respond.js
Options: processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], process=undefined
Options: processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], process=undefined
Copying src/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/admin.js -> public/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/admin.js
Reading src/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/admin.js...OK
Writing public/wp-content/themes/pilau-starter/js/admin.js...OK
```

Comment: What's the output if you run the task with the `--verbose` flag? Also, the `nonull` option can be helpful when debugging.

Comment: Which version of the `grunt-contrib-copy` are you using? You can try to use `processContent` instead of `process` because it was used in v0.4.1 and earlier. You can also try to console log your `breakpoints.large` and `breakpoints.medium` maybe they are not correctly set in your config...

Comment: Are files being copied to the output when this runs?  +1 on the `--verbose` suggestion.

Comment: I tested your Gruntfile extract (with hard-coded variables) and it works perfectly as intended (copies while replacing, logs content). So I would suspect an incorrect variable, most probably `srcThemeDir` as if copy finds no file, process is not executed and you get no log, as you described. Where do you define the variables?

Comment: Apologies for having undeclared vars in there, I've edited and replaced them with the actual paths. Those paths work for everything else. I've also added `--verbose` output - I'm guessing `process=undefined` is the issue? Everything else is working - my edits are copied from src/ to /public fine. `breakpoints` is logging fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of **grunt-contrib-copy** is 0.4.0. As correctly point out by @nemesv above the property name to use in this version would be **`processContent` not `process`**.

I cloned your repo and switched to `json-breakpoints` branch. And ran `grunt copy:js` and it replaced the content.

[image: original-content]
[image: replaced-content]

Now,when you run `grunt copy:js --verbose` it will still show this

[image: cli]

`processContent` is logged undefined because grunt uses `JSON.stringify` to log a value. And `JSON.stringify` returns `undefined` when you pass it a function definition.

---

If you are interested, here's the method reponsible for logging all the option

```
    Log.prototype.writeflags = function(obj, prefix) {
        var wordlist;
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            wordlist = this.wordlist(obj);
        } else if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj) {
            wordlist = this.wordlist(Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
                var val = obj[key];
                return key + (val === true ? '' : '=' + JSON.stringify(val));
            }));
        }
        this._writeln((prefix || 'Flags') + ': ' + (wordlist || '(none)'.cyan));
        return this;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be an issue with the `process` option at all, but more an issue with `srcThemeDir`. I would log it to make sure you know exactly what it is, as it appears that it is causing the `copy` task to not find any files (and therefore not call the process function).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to switch that out. I've replaced it with the value it's set to. The var works fine for everything else. Also see `--verbose` output in edit above, too - files are being found OK it seems. Any edits I make are copied - just the replacement isn't happening.